# Resue previous example in pytest parametrize

Tags: pytest

Consider a parametrized `pytest` test, which reuses the same complex
example a number of times. To keep the sample code as simple as possible,
I have simulated the 'complex' examples with very long integers.

```
from operator import add
from pytest   import mark

parm = mark.parametrize

@parm(' left,       right, result',
      ((9127384955, 1,     9127384956),
       (9127384955, 2,     9127384957),
       (9127384955, 3,     9127384958),
       (9127384955, 4,     9127384959),
       (4729336234, 1,     4729336235),
       (4729336234, 2,     4729336236),
       (4729336234, 3,     4729336237),
       (4729336234, 4,     4729336238),
      ))
def test_one(left, right, result):
    assert add(left, right) == result
```

The first four (and the next four) examples use exactly the same value for `left` but:

- I have to read the examples carefully to realize this
- This repetition is verbose

I would like to make it absolutely clear that **exactly the same
example is being reused** and save myself the need to repeat the same example many times. (Of course, I could bind the example to a global variable, and use that variable, but that variable would have to be bound at some distant point outside of my collection of examples, and I want to see the actual example in the context in which it is used (i.e. near to the other values used in this particular set) rather than having to look for it elsewhere.

Here is an implementation which allows me to make this explicit using a syntax that I find perfectly acceptable, but the implementation itself is horrible: it uses a global variable and doesn't stand a chance of working with distributed test execution.

```
class idem: pass

@parm(' left,       right, result',
      ((9127384955, 1,     9127384956),
       (  idem    , 2,     9127384957),
       (  idem    , 3,     9127384958),
       (  idem    , 4,     9127384959),
       (4729336234, 1,     4729336235),
       (  idem    , 2,     4729336236),
       (  idem    , 3,     4729336237),
       (  idem    , 4,     4729336238),
      ))
def test_two(left, right, result):
    global previous_left
    if left is idem: left          = previous_left
    else           : previous_left = left
    assert add(left, right) == result
```

How can this idea be implemented in a more robust way? Is there some feature built in to pytest that could help?

Comment: I think you shouldn't try to be smart in testing and be as explicit at possible. That way you'll have stable and reliable tests that cannot hide bugs themselves.

Comment: I find clearly-wirtten and legible tests to be the best form of documentation. For that reason I desperately want my tests to be legible. Verbose repetition of the same example, mixed in with subtle variations of examples on some theme, destroys this legibility. If the cost of legibility is being smart in my tests, then it's a cost I'm prepared to pay in many cases.